# How can the scale of a BigDecimal be validated?

Tags: java, validation, exception, bigdecimal

We currently have some code for validating a string as a BigDecimal of the correct scale that looks like:

```
try {
    new BigDecimal(amount).setScale(4);
} catch (Exception e) {
    //...something
}
```

I would prefer it looked a little more like this:

```
if(!BigDecimalValidator.getInstance().isValid(amount)){
   ...something 
}
```

However this validates that the input can be parsed, but does not validate that the scale is correct.

How can this be done using a validator? 
Is the only way to do this by comparing the scale or catching the exception?

Comment: I don't get it. You should *set* the scale that you want, not *require* it.

Comment: @EJP If you use BigDecimal.setScale(int) then an ArithmeticException will be thrown if the specified scaling operation would require rounding.
We cannot guarentee that the BigDecimal will be of the right scale.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#setScale(int)

Answer (score 0):

create a validator and put the code from the first example inside of it.